# double loop vs apply or purrr family

Tags: r, apply, purrr

I have a double loop on my code. Is there one way to do it by apply family or purrr instead of double loop?

Here is my code

```
values<-c(0.2, -0.7, 0.05,
           0.3,0.024,-0.78,
           0.1,0.007,-0.63,
           0.25,0.987, 0.8,
           -0.7,0.8,0.3,
           -0.6, 0.1,0.14,
           0.1, 0.4,0.304) 

mvalues = matrix(values, nrow=7,  ncol=3)

aux<-c(1.25, 1.7,0.8)


x<-matrix(0,nrow=7,ncol=3)
for (i in 1:length(aux)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(mvalues)){
    x[j,i]=mvalues[j,i]*sqrt(aux[i])
  }
}
x
```

Comment: `apply` is for matrices; purrr is for lists (like `lapply`/`mapply`). But in this case you can leverage vector recycling to do it with only matrix operations: `t(t(mvalues) * sqrt(aux))`

Comment: yes of course! its perfect ! thanks @alistaire

Comment: This is a "sweep" operation: `sweep(mvalues, 2, sqrt(aux), "*")`

Comment: @42- I didn't know this function. It's better than loop but slower than matrix operation.